# MarkLogic JavaScript scheduled task

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, marklogic

I try to schedule a script using the 'Scheduled Tasks' in ML8. The documentation explains this a bit but only for xQuery.
Now I have a JavaScript file I'd like to schedule.

The error in the log file:

```
2015-06-23 19:11:00.416 Notice: TaskServer: XDMP-NOEXECUTE: Document is not of executable mimetype. URI: /scheduled/cleanData.js
2015-06-23 19:11:00.416 Notice: TaskServer: in /scheduled/cleanData.js [1.0-ml]
```

My script:

```
/* Scheduled script to delete old data */
var now      = new Date();
var yearBack = now.setDate(now.getDate() - 65);

var date = new Date(yearBack);
var b    = cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("Dtm", "<", date);
var c    = fn.subsequence(cts.uris("", [], b), 1, 10);

while (true) {
    var uri = c.next();

    if (uri.done == true){
        break;
    }

   xdmp.log(uri.value, "info"); // log for testing
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the *.sjs extension (Server-side JavaScript).

The *.js extension can be used for static JavaScript resources to return to the client instead of executed on the server.

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 2):

I believe that ehennum found the issue for you (the extension - which is what the mime-type error is complaining about.

However, on the same subject, not all items in ML work quite as you would expect for Serverside Javascript.  For example, using sjs as a target of a trigger is (or recently) did not work.  So for things like that, it is also possible to wrap the sjs call inside of xqy using xdmp-invoke.

Comment: That has been fixed in either 8.0-2 or 8.0-3, not sure. This gets triggered and executed as expected in 8.0-3 at least: `xdmp.log('*****Document ' + uri + ' was created.*****')` (saved as /test-trigger.sjs in Modules, and yes that is the entire file contents :)

Comment: Yup its fixed now.  But the point is that while sjs is still in its early stages of use, there will likely continue to be some wrinkles.  They, of course will be ironed out as people find them. But in reality, that just takes time and use of the system in real-world scenarios to really find them - and a few more release cycles to fix.  The point is: if you think something is not quite as you expect in such a radically new feature, it is good to take pause and consider all options. after 10 months of playing with sjs, I'm only now really feeling comfortable with it :)